# Preventing access to routes in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my MVC application I have `Player` and `Coach` objects, and a user can be one or the other.  I also have `Team` objects and what I want to know is how I prevent a user who is in a list of `Players` or is the `Coach` of a `Team` gaining access to a route like `/Teams/Details/2` where `2` is the id of a team other than that which he/she is part of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a little terminology nitpick: you are limiting accessq to Controllers, not routes.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, well I still need them to access the Controllers I just don't want users to be able to explicitly pass in an id for a team to the Details method of the Teams controller that is different to the id of the team that they are a part of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to restrict an id that they aren't a part of, this seems like a situation where you can Inherit from the `AuthorizeAttribute` and provide your implementation for `AuthorizeCore`

Your implementation could check their role/team id and decide what to do / redirect.

```
public class TeamAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{

  protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
    return UserIsInTeam(httpContext); //whatever code you are using to check if the team id is right      

  }

}
```

You can now apply it like any other attribute.

```
[TeamAuthorize]
```

Comment: Thank-you! This sounds like an ideal solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest solution would be to change the URLs from using IDs to random GUIDs. You would almost eliminate the chance of someone guessing another valid value. Of course, this is not secure by definition (mostly because someone could get the other URL from history or another source), but in some scenarios this is enough.

A better solution is to create a new attribute based on `IActionFilter` interface that implements `OnActionExecuting` method and checks the ID by using `this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` and `this.RouteData.Values["id"]`. You will then apply this attribute to your controller methods.

In our current system we implemented row level security in controller methods by just adding the code that verifies the user permissions as the first line in each method. The checking code is the same as with the attribute and it requires the same amount of code to add. This approach has one additional benefit - it is easier to implement scenarios like where a coach would be able to see the details of other teams but not modify them (we have one action and view for both reading and updating depending on permissions).

You would also use the last approach if you need to go to the database to check the permissions and you are using IoC frameworks such as Ninject with constructor based injection - since you will not have access to those values in the attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sounds like it's worth considering!